# Object reference method call

Tags: c#, polymorphism

```
void doStuff(Object obj)
{
   obj.method1();
}
```

This code does not compile because the compiler cannot find `method1` in class `Object`, but I know that `obj` will implement this method. I can't cast the object because I don't know the type.

This is possible in VB. How can I do it in c#?

Comment: Is it possible in `VB`? It has been a long time since I used VB, but I seriously doubt it is possible. If it really is possible then yuck.

Comment: Yeah, definitely is possible. I use when I user defined control uses a call method of a web service. The WS is type Object and I just call the method. Is is resolved in runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection to [get the type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the object, [get the method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and call it:

```
    class SomeClass
{
    public void method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method1() called");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void DoStuff(Object obj)
    {
        MethodInfo method = obj.GetType().GetMethod("method1");

        if(method != null) //check for null - that is returned if there is no method1
            method.Invoke(obj, new Object[]{});
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();

        DoStuff(someClass);
    }
}
```

LE: but for us to give better advices, we will need more information about what are you trying to achieve, so you can consider an interface, that might be a better solution than using reflection.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont know which type you Will g'et then use an interface and use This interface as a parameter instead of the type objext ;)